Why was my question closed as story based?
My question was closed for being too story based with no explanation beyond that other than a meme about someone having hot pockets.
I assumed I had met the criteria. It was low concept since it was about a narrow range of activities for a group, there was no character based choice since it was just about the set up for a super hacking group, a common story concept, I clearly limited the concept to modern tech, gave it a budget. Still, it was closed. There is no narrative necessity, since I am simply asking how to build a common set up that nations use with a much larger budget.
My only guess is that people felt that, say, it was narrative necessity because I was against say, the nations backing x group invading the nations backing y group as an alternative to hacking? Is saying no to world war too story based?
Why was it closed?

I voted to close as too story-based because it's an open-ended question where an infinite number of story conditions could be applied to answer the question. That was the point about my link to the movie The Core concerning Xena tapes and hot pockets. What does your crack hacker group need?
Answer: whatever it is that makes them efficient at their job — including Xena tapes and hot pockets. They need couches and free soda and subdued lighting and massages and the right kind of background music....
But even if you're only interested in the technology, do we list the servers? How many? What type? What cooling system? What security protocols? What operating system?
Do we list the terminals? What computers? How many screens? What operating system? Do they have local storage? Do they use cloud storage? Do they have their own cloud storage? How about Faraday protection?
Do we list networking? What service? What physical transport system? What communication protocol? Are we listing hubs? switches? modems? routers? What kind? What size? How many? Do we include satellites?
As a programmer and an electrical engineer, I know that there isn't a single-best-answer to your question. In fact, the only answer to your question is the one that resolves whatever narrative necessity your story demands. Hollywood is constantly showing us new interpretations to the "what do hackers need?" question, from the movie Hackers to any number of Mission Impossible and James Bond movies. It's 100% story based. A good hacker could use an Apple IIe to hack the proverbial NATO Ghost Comm.
And I'm a huge fan of Ving Rhames' response, "...even with top-of-the-line crypto, cray access... thinking machine laptops? I'm talking about the 686 prototypes with the artificial intelligence RISC chip?" It was all wonderful nonsense.
In other words, this isn't a worldbuilding question, it's a storybuilding question, meaning the answer is based too much on story requirements. There is no single definitive and objective answer that's independent of your story.

Wouldn't that apply to almost any question on technology, or on materials? There are almost always countless ways to do technology and countless factors that can be involved in them. The general understanding is you narrow it down to things which have some sort of material impact on the project- e.g. hot pockets and the type of monitor probably don't impact it much, but whether you buy an expensive vs cheap computer do. Also, is narrative logic in movies meant to be a constraint on hard science answers, in that tv shows handle it in divergent ways, and so hard science q need to?

@NepeneNep: I heartily sustain JBH's answer. The question was not about IT. It literally asked "what equipment" was needed. Years ago in my day job I actually did this, for part of the equipment; it was not about hacking, just plain enterprise IT, but believe me the list of equipment is long. Lighting. HVAC. Special lighting and special HVAC for the data center. Desks. Fire suppression. Electric power, complete with UPSes and backup generators. Special floors for the data center. False ceilings for the work rooms. Etc. etc. The computers themselves are a very small part.

It did say "What would be the setup they should build to be really good at cracking enemy systems" not "List every piece of equipment which is needed to support said setup". almost any question is going to have essentially infinite variations if you consider outside factors that could impact them or supporting factors. Should we close every question which has outside factors that could impact them? "E.g. What goods yield the best profit for time-travel arbitrage?" trading has infinite variation.

@NepeneNep "What would be the setup" only has a specific and defined meaning to you. To the rest of the world it can mean anything, including Xena tapes and hot pockets. Have you ever talked to a hacker? I have. Chairs are important. Easy access to food is important. "Setup" does NOT have a specific, definitive, or objective meaning.

I raised a new question on this. I feel it's deeply problematic if you are applying this criteria to closures in general, because almost every question has infinite factors that could impact support. https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10422/outside-factors-shouldnt-be-a-consideration-in-whether-to-close-a-question

Story Based was Accurate

I had nothing to do with the VTC. Whenever queries like this end up being brought to Meta, I offer the best outsider & dispassionate perspective I can. I read your question, the comments, the closure reasons, and the answers you received. I'd have to say that, given what I read, I'd agree with the VTC rational for the following reasons, though there are other possibilities:

You literally asked for a (long) list of equipment: What equipment would be needed for a top of the line hacking group?  I look at this two ways. First, a query asking for a list of things is essentially you asking for brainstorming help. Such sessions are essential for worldbuilding and storycraft, but they are also off topic here. Second, your question could be read as what would your group choose, given the budget and availability of literally everything on the planet. This is the heart of the story based query: what would my characters choose? It's almost never a good sign when a querent begins her question with "In my story..." because the question almost always ends up being more about the story than about the world.

You're not actually asking a worldbuilding question. We have this go-around once or twice a month here, the most recent being a question about Venus. The issue here is the same as the issue there: this question has no worldbuilding context. From reading your question, I gather that you've got the world or the setting the story takes place in already built. Furthermore, it looks like your world is either very similar to or identical with the Real World. This makes your job easy, but it makes our job pretty much impossible, because we can't focus on real world questions here. Stack Exchange has other forums where you could ask this question and get answers based on real world experience. The answers you got here reflect that, and given that nothing "fictional" was asked and nothing "fictional" was given in response indicate that this forum was not the best forum to ask in. So, you didn't ask a "bad question", I'd say you asked a "good question" in the wrong forum.

In comments you brought up an excellent point about Real World Questions. This community does have a policy relating to such questions. Simply because WB.SE is a (relatively small) subset of Stack Exchange, we recognise that there are other forums that are competent to address problems, issues, and situations that a worldbuilder might be wrestling with but that don't really touch on the nature of the fictional world itself.
For example, a querent might be building a world in which there is a country that has a Parliament. She doesn't know how parliaments actually parliament, so she asks the question here in Worldbuilding. "Simple question with an undoubtedly complex answer: how does the UK Parliament actually function?"
We would close this question (hopefully sooner rather than later) not because it's a bad question, but because it's a real world question that's better handled in the History or Politics forums. The question has no substantial fictional world context and is thus a question type that we have chosen, at this time, to not deal with.
As with your own question, this situation can be avoided by the simple expedient of following point 2, asking a question about worldbuilding. Context is key here. If there were a way you could have asked this question that would clearly relate your problem (a knowledge deficit) to the fictional world your story is set in, we'd be having a very different conversation right now.
We don't set the bar very high, but we do need more context than "I'm building a world, so here's my real world question". Without this context, the question can often literally be answered by one of us googling the information for the querent. Essentially, this kind of question turns us into a free research service.

Some specific points that I feel deserve to be examined:
a. Your question format is actually quite good! As you say, low concept, narrow scope, clear vision, basic criteria, etc.
b. "No character based choice" is debatable. As I said above, your question could be read as "what should my characters choose". Coupled with the substance of the question itself, this could well be the best reason for voting to close.
c. I would have liked to agree with you on narrative necessity, but now that you bring it up, and as I reread the question in this context, it's very clear to me now that narrative necessity would have also been a valid VTC rationale. I look at it like this. You have two competing groups. Both seem to have large budgets and access to any piece of equipment, tool, or software available on the planet. Obviously, the answer to your query is therefore the protagonists need that one piece of equipment, that one software, that one genius hacker, that the other guys lack. Once this is in place, they'll be able to tip the balance and win the struggle. And they all lived happily ever after. Until our next episode! There's nothing inherently wrong with narrative necessity, but again, this kind of query is more about story arc, plot development, and character choice than about world.
d. Saying no to war is in fact most definitely story based! You're writing a story. It has characters, setting, plot. Whether there's war or not is your choice as writer!
e. Infinite Lists are an issue we've dealt with in the past. As you point out in your comment, infinite lists are problematic in questions. Whenever a query asks for an infinite (or even just really long) list of things, we have to point out that such questions may be good questions, but are simply not a good fit for Stack Exchange. As I said in point 1, brainstorming is a good and essential part of worldbuilding. Stack Exchange is NOT set up for brainstorming, for list generation, for discussion questions or for blatant opinion based questions.
Stack Exchange's model as implemented in Worldbuilding is literally "you ask a targeted and focused question about your fictional world; we give you creative and well thought out answers to your question; you choose which answer best suits your needs (or choose none!); optionally you can choose to refine & reformulate your question into a new question and ask that.



Given that there are multiple real life tags and questions, I feel your answer that you are closing based on real world questions being real is very problematic. Lots of good questions are variations of mine, asking "how do you set up a weird place in a particular time of history", and if you're voting to close all those you have problematic closing priorities. Also, almost any question about tech or magic has a functionally infinite list of things that could set it up. https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/129380/anatomically-correct-triskelion it could evolve with anything.

So again, I don't think you're applying the same criteria to your own questions (How does my creature interact with every possible creature in the history of the universe and evolve) and are closing tech based things based on them having an infinite list of possible items (How do we set up a narrowly functional technical place) when for both the obvious answer is that people can just narrow it down to some key salient details.
Also, hard science was a tag. I don't think there's a hard science precedence that one equipment or hacker solves hacking issues. Hard science =/ narrative logic.

@NepeneNep -- 1. You bring up another good point --- and another valid closure reason! All add that to my answer!

@NepeneNep -- I saw what you did there.  You threw in a little hyperbole when it comes to the creature questions, but swept under the rug one of the main problems with your own question. The simple fact is: we regularly close questions of the type you say we don't close. The classic worldbuilding blunder here is "how would X affect society" where X is some magical or fantastical gizmo and society is not defined. These questions are inherently too broad, opinion based, ask for long lists of things and lack focus. I don't think these are "bad questions". Like yours, they're just (cont)

(cont) not a good fit for SE. And just to reiterate, it's not the respondent's job to "narrow it down". That's the querent's job. As for the hard science tag, I'm not exactly sure where you were going with that one. I saw the notification that your query asked for hard science, but I think the tag had been edited out. As a matter of ethics, I personally avoid answering hard science queries because I'm not a scientician or a researcher or an engineer. That said, I wasn't really certain how hard sciency things like equations, laws of nature or peer reviewed journal articles would (cont)

(cont) provide for a substantially better answer for your question. That tag literally says: * For questions that require unequivocal proof that answers are correct through the use of equations, empirical evidence, scientific papers, etc.* I personally don't see how it applies to your question, but I'm certainly willing to be convinced!

"Given the physical form of the Triskelion and what little is known of its anatomy, physiology and behaviour; how might such a creature evolve?" I wasn't doing hyperbole. You asked for how something evolved, and the evolution of something relies on the entire history of the planet and every organism or feature it evolved with. They need food, lighting, ceilings, and floors, weapons against enemies, just as programmers need those. It's not our job to narrow down broad questions about society, but every question requires some narrowing.

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/168414/question-on-creature-locomotion-ratios you didn't address terrain, food, lighting they were running in. https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/148073/at-what-point-does-a-worlds-twin-planet-disappear-from-the-viewers-perspectiv you didn't address how well fed the viewer was, their eyesight quality, the lighting around them, use of equipment to enhance vision, whether the viewer was in a building or not, lots of stuff. There's always random details that need to be narrowed down. Almost no question is a good fit under that.

@NepeneNep -- I dealt with this in your other comments. If you have a problem with a question that I wrote, just start a new Meta question. Using my question to either defend the deficiencies in your own or to in some way besmirch my replies to your question only serve to diminish your own argument. In other words, you messed up, you got called out, you complained, we explained, and now you're looking to point fingers.

I am simply noting that this is a criteria you are applying to my question but not others. You should be applying consistent criteria to all questions for closure.

@NepeneNep --- Let's stay on topic. If you have a problem with a question that I wrote, just start a new Meta question.

I can't say that I felt that the closed question was Too Story Based.  It seemed to be entirely about the technology in my opinion.  Perhaps some of the close voters thought that it was 'not about worldbuilding,' given that it was about real-world technology, but the last close voter selected TSB... and the last close vote's reason wins and gets displayed on closed questions to those with the VTC privilege.
There seems to be a trend of late to be quick to close questions, and the users responsible for this closure are responsible for many of the other closures I see these days.  While I close a few questions, since my close vote is effectively a one-shot mod-hammer, I'm very careful to only close those questions that really need to be closed, or as the last vote of three or four pre-existing votes.
The presence of my answer should show at least that I didn't think that it should be closed.  Unfortunately, I can't quite justify unilaterally mod-hammering it back open either.
If the question was edited to show how it isn't too story based, and that it has worldbuilding relevance, some users might vote to re-open... and I might add my vote to theirs.

It was not about computing technology. It literally asked "what equipment". To take a trivial example, one could easily write a fifteen hundred word essay only about lighting; I know because I once had to do it for a client. Then consider the desks. Decompression rooms. Etc.

I don't think bureaucracy for setting up projects should generally be considered for closure reasons. Not every question needs to handle the bureaucracy of how to set up a large project. I was only concerned notably about computing technology- I didn't ask how to make programmers comfortable so they could succeed at the task, I asked what equipment for hacking was needed. If the programmers fail because they lack lighting or decompression rooms, that's a story issue, and doesn't matter to my question of whether their hacking equipment is good.

"the last close vote's reason wins and gets displayed on closed questions to those with the VTC privilege." No, it is not. The logic is far more coherent and sensible than "last one in sits on top". There are in fact two reasons for closure in the banner, meaning both options were chosen by at least two users each.
