Outside factors shouldn't be a consideration in whether to close a question
I raised a previous question, and it revealed what I see as a very troubling tendency in close votes.

I voted to close as too story-based because it's an open-ended
question where an infinite number of story conditions could be applied
to answer the question. That was the point about my link to the movie
The Core concerning Xena tapes and hot pockets. What does your crack
hacker group need?
Answer: whatever it is that makes them efficient at their job —
including Xena tapes and hot pockets. They need couches and free soda
and subdued lighting and massages and the right kind of background
music....

JBH

I heartily sustain JBH's answer. The question was not about IT. It
literally asked "what equipment" was needed. Years ago in my day job I
actually did this, for part of the equipment; it was not about
hacking, just plain enterprise IT, but believe me the list of
equipment is long. Lighting. HVAC. Special lighting and special HVAC
for the data center. Desks. Fire suppression. Electric power, complete
with UPSes and backup generators. Special floors for the data center.
False ceilings for the work rooms. Etc. etc. The computers themselves
are a very small part.

AlexP
I think this shows a problematic trend in voting which is likely to close many questions. On literally any question you can always look at an essentially infinite array of outside factors that could influence the core issue, and those two people used their experience in IT as guidance on whether to close.
E.g. "Take What goods yield the best profit for time-travel arbitrage?" sales depends on food, on lighting on how you sell it with music, on an essentially infinite variation of sales pitches. Advertising is a billion dollar business.
"Why would radio-capable transhumans still vocalise to each-other?" Communication relies on nutrition and there's an essentially infinite array of foods and exercises which determine the strength of vocalization and the nature.
The reason why my and other posts got closed and theirs didn't is likely because those two people above and others have experience in IT and so are interested in the infinite variety of conditions that can apply for optimizing efficiency and nuanced details of how you do it, but do not have experience in time travel and radio capable transhumanism and so didn't care about the variations in those.
Close votes shouldn't be based on you having a more in depth knowledge of a subject, or an interest in films and therefore a good concept of narrative logic on the subject and therefore knowing that there are an infinite variation of things you can do for a subject. It's the job of people making answers to narrow down on key interesting world building elements. Unless there's a specific request like "Tell me every possible technology needed to enable this feature" which would be basically build my world for me and closeworthy, then you shouldn't assume they care about support technologies like lighting, or narrative logic in how it was shown on tv- you should assume they want key salient details, not supporting technology.

Unless you specify what "outside factors" means in terms of your question, we have no ability to know what you think it means without the ability to read your mind. I know you don't believe this, but your question was not as clear as you think it was and it's not the job of everyone else to just deal with it. What equipment do I like when I progam? Headphones and music, dim lighting, access to the VI editor (yeah, I'm old fashioned). What you asked for and what you're now asking for simply isn't reasonable. You, the OP, need to be clear and not assume we all should know what you mean.

For literally every question involving humans, there are outside factors you could use. https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/248981/detectability-of-a-type-iii-civilization-with-a-specific-set-of-conditions this say, detecting a type iii civilization is deeply dependent on lighting and headphones and buildings and telescopes and music and access to software and there are numerous versions of each. Like, if there's no lighting in the building, how can they detect a dyson sphere. Does that mean we need to close your question as you didn't address what lighting there was?

I get your complaints, Nep... but it doesn't change the fact that in my opinion your question failed to be specific about what you wanted. I'm an electrical engineer, and I'm not able to jump to an easy conclusion about what you wanted in terms of an answer because, whether you like it or not, it's not that simple. You needed to be specific about what you wanted. You weren't.

Nor were you, nor are most questions. Outside factors like lighting and food supplies impact lots of questions, but are generally ignored because people assume they can handle that. If you're closing questions based on that you're probably using bad closing standards which hurt membership on the stack, standards you don't apply to your own questions.

I'm a programmer, Nep. The programmer's comfort is not a trivially ignored aspect of programming. Major companies like Microsoft and Google spend outrageous amounts of money on programmer comfort, which has NOTHING to do with the equipment they use to program. You're trying to make a comparison that doesn't make sense, suggesting strongly that you don't understand what you're asking about. Frankly, it's insulting to be told by an amateur who hasn't performed any real research into the issue that I'm wrong. I didn't hold your question to a double standard - you're just refusing to learn.

Yes, that's my point- the programmer comfort has nothing to do with the equipment used to hack. It influences it yes, and the failure to have such might doom it just in your question the failure to have good lighting might prevent discovery of a dyson sphere, but not every question about programming needs to handle the in depth issues of lighting and food supplies. You see me as insulting, but you ignored those questions for your own world. Because, people regularly leave some details to the side for questions. Your standards for closing are unreasonable because of your job, and inconsistent.

I'll also note, the programmer comfort is a story question about whether the programmer succeeds in whatever story task. If they are uncomfortable and the project fails, that doesn't change the correctness of an answer about hacking equipment. I and many questions don't ask "How do we succeed at x task" where comfort is important, we ask how to set up the equipment. Bureaucracy of how to ensure programmers are comfortable is normally a story question about success rates, not a world building question about equipment, and should generally be ignored. Most questions are not asking for success.

I understand your frustration; many commenters ask for details that are ultimately irrelevant or at least not needed to answer the question at hand. That said, users here can never read the OP's mind, and many questions suffer from a Frame Challenge.

@NepeneNep: Just to let you know, I liked the theme of your question. I would have made suggestions on how to get more focus in there, but we surely would have had worked out the core of your concern. As you see here, opinion vs. opinion leads to nowhere. I just hope, you continue using WB:SE would be sad to loose a creative mind like yours.

Who defines what an "outside factor" is?
When you say "outside factors" what you mean is, "influences, conditions, or restrictions that I, the OP, deem irrelevant to the question." The problem, of course, is if you don't explain what you consider "outside factors" to be, the rest of us, who might actually be experts in the premise of the question who exceed your own experience, will choose how to react to your question based on our own experience rather than your undefined and undeclared expectations.
Because we can't read your mind
The simple reality is that no user can read the OP's mind. What seems to you like an obvious outside factor may be judged substantially influential by someone more experienced in the subject. In such cases, the only option the OP has is to specifically explain what they expect in an answer. Not surprisingly, that's actually a requirement for a good question on Stack Exchange. Said another way, the more you assume your intentions should be obvious, the more your question should be closed.
How do Frame Challenges fit into all this?
In the case of a well-defined question that is based on a faulty premise, we have the tradition of a Frame Challenge. Simply, Frame Challenges propose an alternative solution after pointing out and correcting the faulty premise. But a Frame Challenge couldn't be used here because the question has a systemic flaw: it's too broad. Even if we all were to agree that equipment is the only rational way to answer the question there are simply too many factors involving the programmer's personal taste. Monitors are the worst offender. One or many? Large or small? Which brand? There's no way to use a Frame Challenge because there isn't one, definitive answer.
Worse still is the equipment that isn't within range of the programmer's sense of touch — equipment you may deem to be "outside factors" because they aren't the proverbial hammer in the programmer's hand. Networking and biometric security come to mind. And then there's the personal choices of what software to use because there is no library of software (and it's a library, not just one title) that's in any way "the best."
Conclusion
This is why I down voted this post. An "outside factor" as defined by and assumed by the OP will never be applicable to the entirety of the community and there will never be a single definition we all can or will agree on. If the OP is unwilling to explain how they'll choose a best answer, then the OP is stuck dealing with what the rest of us assume the answer can be.
And I've voted to close a great many quesitons based on the issue of "how will you judge a best answer?" In this case, however, I did fail you. Rather than clearly explaining my issue at the beginning, I left you with a movie quote and assumed you'd understand the problem. In that regard you and I made the same mistake.
But here we are now, two Meta questions and a great deal of explanation later and we're still debating the issue. It's the OP's job to be specific and to set expectations, not the community's job to figure out what the OP thinks the minimum set of valid answers should be.

I'll list the outside factors you gave- 1. Whether they have food. 2. Whether they have lighting. 3. Whether they have music. 4. Whether they have free massages. 5. Whether they have lesbian homoerotic tv to watch. 5. Whether they have furniture. And for others. 6. Fire suppression. 7. Ceilings. 8. Floors. 9. AC units. 10. Nuclear bombs. 11. Whether they can buy things. Most of the factors, while important, are not closely related to the task at hand. They are moderately challenging tasks to fulfill sure, but you don't need to close a question over whether they can buy hotpockets.

@NepeneNep Those aren't outside factors, they're real factors in the whether the set up is adequate, for anything, except the nukes, those are a little bit exceptional even here.

By outside factors, I mean issues that may determine the success or failure of the project but which aren't uniquely related to the core question. Food is important, and without it programmers starve, but in a city it's very easy to get. There are catering companies, you can buy food in bulk, hire cooks or train them, and it's not generally a failure point for hacking. Any question for humans needs food, but unless survival away from cities is mentioned, it's an outside factor. Anything that you can just buy easily in a city and need for literally any question is an outside factor.

@NepeneNep We've spoken enough. You haven't the slightest idea what you're talking about when it comes to hackers and refuse to listen to people who do. Next time, write a better question rather than whining about how anyone failed to read your mind.

I think me pointing out the trivial nature of many closure reasons is important, and will keep doing so. I am not discounting your personal experiences that lighting and food and massages and ceilings and floors are important and take a lot of work to get right, but they take a lot of work to get right for almost every large project. Not every questions needs to remake the wheel on how to have a functional bureaucracy that lets people work. And, people do ignore those issues for most questions which aren't related to their core expertise areas. Disagreement isn't whining.

I was one of those who VTC'd the original question and did so entirely on the basis that the usefulness of any answer is totally story dependent. For a start the term "modern technology" when dealing with computers is worse than useless as any "cutting edge" equipment isn't by the time it ships.
Then in no particular order:

Where are they working out of? If they have access to an existing data centre then their new equipment needs are relatively low, if starting from scratch that's a different story, if working from someone's basement that's yet another.
What timeframe do they have? If they need to information yesterday hacking may simply not be effective at all, if they have a year or two then they could get away with off the shelf, or even secondhand, hardware and mum's dial up connection.
How exposed are they comfortable getting? If they can afford to do things the quick and dirty way such that their opposite numbers know they're getting done over then that's completely different from a stealth hack that leaves no trace.
How much firepower does the "not hacking in" side of the operation have access to? You've said "basically unlimited resources", if you can roll tanks and run drones, hell for the kind of money you mentioned they could bribe their way into an actionable volume of fissile material or even some working nuclear warheads. Different assumptions around various options here changes the whole dynamic/balance of the overall team and totally alters the role of the IT department in the operation.

In short your question lacks the limitations to be answerable, because we don't know where or how the outcome sits in your story.
And for the record I only know enough about computers to get myself in serious trouble before I yell for IT support. I have no clue what goes in to a large scale computer lab/operation and I still see vast issues with the scope of the question you have asked.

The first factor is something that you should generally assume organizations have access to- they can buy or build things that are commonly available. A lot of questions fail if you assume they are unable to buy commonly available modern technology. https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/259736/is-the-proposed-solar-sailing-race-course-possible fails say if you assume they can't build or buy technology. You didn't define if whatever organization was able to buy technology. I'll note for that question you didn't define the timeframe, if it was secret, or...

How they would handle invasion. In general, most questions by you and others don't handle infrastructure capacities, buying abilities, how to handle invasion, how to handle secrecy. Those are factors that could be important for a story, and if the race track also needs to nuke natives to get rights to the area that is a story, but it's not something you should assume. In general, you shouldn't assume outside factors unrelated to the story are in play. You should assume they can buy or build appropriate stuff, avoid assuming invasion is happening, and that they have appropriate time to do it.

That's a sci-fi question that deliberately put no boundaries on the technology/resources involved, up to and including building a whole star system from scratch, I admit it should have had more limits than it did, I was thinking small when I said "using whatever technology suits". Many of my questions are about how to define infrastructure capacity in a particular sci-fi setting. I didn't assume anything, I looked at the parameters you had set and said that the usefulness of any answer was highly dependent on the roadblocks and capabilities you created as an author that you hadn't defined.

That's the sort of thing I mean- you don't know the intricacies of sci fi technology, and so you didn't put in many limits. You do know some of the limitations of real life and so you closed my question, and probably other questions because of potential real life limitations because I didn't address time frame, war abilities, stealth, and whether they could get technology. Those four issues are an issue for your sci fi questions, but because you are not an expert on building sci fi race tracks, you ignored them. You shouldn't apply a harsher criteria to modern tech than sci fi.

@NepeneNep How do I put this, you gave a set of capabilities for the protagonists, then didn't define their level of access, or anything about their opposition, in the question. Therefore the usefulness of our answers depends on undefined elements of the story, thus the "too story based" VTC.

You also didn't define your alien species level of access, or their opposition (as mentioned they wanted to hide details from racers, so there's presumably ways to spy on them) either in your question. That is fairly normal- in questions not every aspect of the setting is laid out, especially when it is unimportant. If you are closing questions because they didn't define how they would wage nuclear against their opposition or whether they could buy items, you are providing an unreasonable standard you don't apply to your own questions involving sci fi.

@NepeneNep Yes I did, I defined it as no limits on any side, there was no opposition whatsoever to deal with, except the laws of physics. The builders wanted a natural effect that was aesthetically pleasing, it simply had the advantage of making life harder for the racers as well because they then wouldn't be able to read the course conditions easily.

I checked, and you didn't define any of those limits. You may have defined them in your head, but you didn't state them in the question. Naturally, because people don't define every aspect of their stories when they pose a question. I know it's easy to critique questions about earth because you know more so it's easier to make something up, but you shouldn't apply different standards to sci fi vs real life.

@NepeneNep "anything goes" is a defined limit and that is stated in the question, thus JBH's answer and my confusion with it, I had defined very different limits in my head to what I actually stated in the question. You gave approximately a third of the limits we needed to answer the question properly, including not defining a desired outcome.

You said that they had whatever techniques were needed and they had whatever technology suits, you didn't say that anything goes or that there were no limits. You also didn't answer your four criteria- opposition, ability to buy goods, timeframe, secrecy levels. You didn't give enough limits to give an answer by your own standards. Which is because, it's an issue of the story handling opposition, buying goods, deciding on a timeframe, and how secret it's meant to be, not an issue you need to decide for an answer. I didn't ask to keep it secret, help wage war, help buying stuff, or do it fast.

@NepeneNep "whatever technology suits" includes Clarketech which means anything goes, up to and including simply creating a universe in which the proposed object just does exist, because you can, repeatedly, and with no more effort than breathing. When it comes to Clarketech the word opposition is meaningless, buy what? It all just appears, timeframe becomes whenever I snap my fingers, secrecy yes, no, whatever I decide whenever I decide it. There is no equivalent to that when you're setting is something like the real world.

Your tag on that question was science based, and creating a universe is beyond what science can plausibly do. Clarketech is essentially magical technology per your link, which is not plausible under scientific laws. The fact that you need to resort to magic as an explanation for why you are not applying a different standard is troubling. You are assuming your answers are fine because they could be justified under magic technology, despite using the science based tag, and closing other questions based on modern life.

@NepeneNep Yes the tag didn't match the question as written, I have fixed it. You are effectively arguing that a question that deserves a negative score is a paragon. Even if it were it's not a question about the real world, it's about a hypothetical environment. Your question is fundamentally about a theoretical real world conflict, it has at least two sides but it gives only partial details about one of those sides.

Your question still does the same, in that it gives a lot of information about the creators of the race, but not the creators of the racees, or their technology or ability to win races. How can you hide from someone trying to predict the nature of a race and cheat when they can create a universe where they won and predict exactly what will happen say? Or look into the future and see optically what happened in the race? Having clarketech in the area makes the opposition even more complicated, not less. In both our questions, while there was a conflict, we didn't ask to solve that conflict.

@NepeneNep There IS NO CONFLICT in my question, there is only a clearly stated goal, your question has a conflict, against an unknown enemy, and NO clearly stated goal. The races that may or may not be run on the course are immaterial to whether or not the race course can exist which is all I asked for "Is the proposed solar sailing race course possible?". As it turns out no it weighs far too much.

Yes, as Vilarinof said, you artificially set up a conflict between the racers who have to win or maybe die and the creators who want the racers to see it as natural. By your own standards, that means your question is left open. Introducing clarketech heightens the conflict even more. This is very common in questions, and you've probably closed a bunch of questions with similar conflicts just as unresolved as your own. That means you're applying different standards to your questions vs others.

@Vilarinof The people creating it are the "other side" you are suggesting exists, there is no conflict, there is a single unified goal.

@NepeneNep No, the racers and also products of the course designers, no conflict exists.

Yeah, but you explained almost nothing about them. They have spaceships to fly through this arena, but if clarketech exists, why wouldn't they have the ability to create universes where they won? Them being created by aliens doesn't mean they can't create a universe where they won, or use time travel. You roasted me over the coals for not explaining my antagonists in depth, and you did almost nothing for yours. Not that you should have to, because not every question needs to explain everything.

@NepeneNep -- I see you're trying the same tactic here. You got busted and your tactic now is to go searching for questions we wrote to whine about "He did the same thing I did! Why isn't his question closed!" Well boo hoo. If your tactic is now to point fingers, then I would strongly suggest that you don't actually have a legitimate basis for an argument. Give it a rest, please. We're trying to help you understand what wrong. Take what we're saying with the appropriate doses of salt, move on and ask better questions next time!

"
The reason why my and other posts got closed and theirs didn't is likely because those two people above and others have experience in IT and so are interested in the infinite variety of conditions that can apply for optimizing efficiency and nuanced details of how you do it, but do not have experience in time travel and radio capable transhumanism and so didn't care about the variations in those." I stated this issue at the start. Notably, they clearly felt their question did meet the criteria initially, and argued for it. It's valuable to reflect on if your closure standards are the same

This is also a meta post about inconsistent closure things. I don't have records of all your closures to compare, so it's natural to look at your posts which you presumably feel meet all appropriate rules to see if you are applying your stated closure standards appropriate. And generally, people are not. People are disagreeing with me about what's wrong, and it's ok. Discussion helps clarify issues and explain things. It's not whining or me being "busted" to disagree about closure standards on a stack exchange.

@NepeneNepn I have zero experience in IT and still see glaring issues with the question you have asked, I have enumerated them for your edification take the education on offer and do better next time, or not, I'm done with the troll feeding in this case.

An Exercise in Reinventing the Wheel!

If I understand your argument properly, you're advocating, essentially, for respondents to be constrained by either arbitrary or non-arbitrary conditions that you as querent have determined are irrelevant. For example, you list a number of things that JBH mentioned as fulfilling your question, but are in fact "outside factors" that you feel have no bearing on your question.

I'll list the outside factors you gave- 1. Whether they have food. 2. Whether they have lighting. 3. Whether they have music. 4. Whether they have free massages. 5. Whether they have lesbian homoerotic tv to watch. 5. Whether they have furniture. And for others. 6. Fire suppression. 7. Ceilings. 8. Floors. 9. AC units. 10. Nuclear bombs. 11. Whether they can buy things. Most of the factors, while important, are not closely related to the task at hand. They are moderately challenging tasks to fulfill sure, but you don't need to close a question over whether they can buy hotpockets.


What makes your point very interesting to me is that, in essence, you've just reinvented (in part) our policy on how to write a good worldbuilding question! These questions come up here in Meta from time to time, and I've answered a share.

It's too late to edit your question now, because it has answers, but for future reference I think there are a couple key take away points:

Always ask the question you actually want to have answered. Writing the question the right way will avoid many VTCs. When a question is closed, don't seek to blame those who VTCed. Look at the question first!

Always define terms and set expectations. The respondent rarely has much insight into your world or your story. She can only answer your question based on what you write in that question. She can only give you an exceptional answer if you are clear as to what you're really looking for and what your expectations are.

How you write a question affects how we write answers. The text of your question is your chance to constrain our cadre of excitable and eager respondents! You happened to ask a question that several people have real life experience with. They're going to write you a text book on the topic if you don't restrain them within your question! As a querent, it really is up to you to write a question in such a way that you'll get results that are useful to you!

"It's the job of people making answers to narrow down on key interesting world building elements". This is most certainly NOT the case! As a respondent, it is NOT my job to figure out what the querent really means when she writes a question! My job as respondent is to take the question I'm asked, apply it to the context of the fictional world presented in the query and devise an answer that a) satisfies the constraints of the question, b) displays creativity, c) offers content that is both useful and engaging to both the present querent and also anyone else who comes here in the future. Honestly, JBH's quip about Xena movies and HotPockets could have been parlayed into a truly creative answer to the question you actually asked!

"You shouldn't assume they care about support technologies like lighting, or narrative logic in how it was shown on tv- you should assume they want key salient details, not supporting technology". This is also NOT the case! It is not the job of the respondent to make assumptions about what the querent thinks is relevant or important. It is not even our job to make assumptions about anything relating to your fictional world. Reason being, we didn't make your world or write your story. We don't know it the way you do!

Write a question about your world, not your story. This should go without saying, but we are in fact a forum whose purpose is to help you build your fictional world. Think of us as another set of eyes that can help you with a problem you're facing or an issue you're experiencing with the nature of your world or setting. Many times, querents do confuse story with setting. We must always keep in mind that elements of storycraft --- characters & plot --- are considered separate from setting, which falls under our domain. A story's setting is the "world" the story happens in, and that's what we deal with.



https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/129380/anatomically-correct-triskelion you don't follow those criteria with your own questions. You ask how a creature evolved in the context of every other creature in the universe. You didn't narrow it down, you didn't set expectations of a time period for evolution. For fantasy and sci fi, people routinely make it the job of the respondent to make assumptions about what is important. We have modern age as a tag for a reason. You are meant to have questions about real life alternate worlds.

@NepeneNep --- Brilliant tactic! When you're called out on an error, just point your finger at others and whine "But! But he did it too!"  Do I need to point out to you that there is actually a way of handling this that doesn't make your complaint look juvenile?

Criteria for closure should be consistent. My point at the start was that people apply different criteria to questions that are within their normal experience (IT, real life supply issues) and different ones to sci fi and fantasy. It's valuable to see that they don't apply the same criteria to similar questions.

@NepeneNep --- If you've got a new issue, then start a new question! Right now, we're dealing with yours.

There are two problems involved here:
(A) [Closed] has a very finite connotation
(B) VTC is easier than suggesting improvements or (help to) rephrase the question. The option to VTC being offered invites to think that "this is the right way to do it"
Using the VTC feature mainly and justifying it with "upholding holy principles" is the culture of WB:SE right now and it is nothing short of being toxic (imho)
ACTUALLY: "Closed" is not too bad. There is a large box inviting everyone to "improve" the question, that is essentially what we all want: improved "good" questions.
Problem 1: There is no way of improving the answer without getting in contact with the OP.
Problem 2: "Closed" right now implies "This question is done. No further work needed/wanted/required". This sends the wrong message to anybody who would be willing and able to help bring the question into shape. It also discourages any and all questioneers to continue using WB:SE if they experienced this once.
I think there should be new rules for VTC and downvote; Essentially there should be a sandbox stage like this:

If there is a new question and you downvote it to get it to -1, you are obliged to edit the question and add a [SANDBOX] tag in front of the title. Then your deed is done. Please refrain from VTC.
Everyone who is not willing to help on [SANDBOX] tags is requested to ignore those questions. Do not downvote, VTC or something else. Be patient.
All others will try help the OP to improve the question via comments and flagging "done" comments with "outdated" to remove them. If OP is responsive and the question therefore is likely being improved, voting the question up (at least to 0) is mandatory (actually, goes without saying).
Once done and the question is regarded as "well-formed", the [SANDBOX] tag is removed and the show begins.
If after a month of no updates the [SANDBOX] tag is still present, the question can be closed or deleted because of missing updates/interest.
Everyone profits.

And for Etiquette:

It is considered rude to contribute nothing but to downvote the question or the only answer on a question to negative or post a VTC without prior contribution. To contribute provide either improvements to the question or post an answer or a comment ("Here is a way to rephrase your question: ...") or tag with [SANDBOX] as seen above.
It is considered rude to just state "This is too XY" without also stating what could be done to avoid that "trap" or asking OP constructive questions in the comments. In this case you just want to [SANDBOX] as seen above probably.


I believe I have two fans. No matter what I post, it gets near instantly voted to -2. lol.

(1) comment-on-Downvote was proposed hundreds or thousands of times on Meta.SE and it was denied every time. One of the reasons: votes are anonymous. Forcing comments would remove anonymity. (2) The code of conduct forbids adding such a [sandbox]-tag (it's no improvement of the question!), and we do never put tags in titles as policy. (3) We can not alter the Stack's behavior. "Closed" used to be listed "on hold" in the first 48 hours, but that was removed years ago. Closed does not mean permanently closed, it means there are problems to resolve.

(4) You want people to ignore content they feel have problems? That demand does not muster up to the policies of Worldbuilding.SE. (5) The flagging reason you look for is no longer needed. (6) your Etiquette proposal is, to be frank, absolutly lacking backing. considered rude by whom? Downvoting and VTC are essential tools of community moderation on SE, commenting another. DVs also trigger the roomba that deletes questions with 0 or negative score and no answer with a score of above 1 after a certain time, including closed questions.

@Trish: Did you realize that almost everyone is not happy of how WB:SE is handling new users (since the beginning 10 years ago)? And the only reason you provide for it is "policy". Yeah okay granted. But what are the points which would improve the situation? All you say is "no, no, no, no" essentially. Especially to (6) By the users. Every user who gets VTC. That is "who". Have a look into Meta. Many posts about essentially the same topic: VTC and rudeness (aka not helping but closing or downvoting).

And to (2) It is to be considered an improvement, because it will get updates. And (1) How comfy to be able to rise the own opinion over that of the other just by hitting DV and stay anonymous. While the other does not have such tools. I do not think they are essential tools especially not in bold face. They are just essential to exert power over others. That is not moderation.

There are blog posts by the founders discussing the decisions that informed the design of Stack Oveflow. In the numerous discussions of a mandatory comment to down vote feature they have laid out their reasoning for rejecting it both because of problems with it having the intended effect and because it does conflict with their explicitly stated design goals. There are other less opinionated question and answer sites that don't place as many restrictions on what can be asked. Part of the value proposition of this site is that it is more structured and opinionated.

If you read the [tour] one of the first things they say is that we are different from other question and answer sites. The rest of it is focused on explaining how we are different and what sort of questions we are looking for.

@sphennings and if you are looking at the questions that get closed into the face of new users and the feedback on Meta, you would see that the current workflow and state-of-mind towards "unfit questions" is suboptimal.

I have an example where the tone and the appreciation of new users is more like I imagine it to be: Gad8teer is a new user, first posting of yesterday. You should have seen his first draft. That was an invitation to VTC-Bam-Done-I did my part. But look at the evolution now. Also Trish is witness of it. And I really love how she is handling things with constructive feedback. I think we have won a user and upholding principles. You see what I mean? https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/261316/how-much-easier-harder-would-it-be-to-colonize-space-if-humans-found-a-method-of

Link to Gad8teer's 2nd question (currently closed, but work in progress: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/261322/is-it-plausible-for-a-new-technology-to-provide-full-immersion-networked-virtua

@Antares Please do not gender me. Not he, not she. At best "they" but preferably just use 3rd person "Trish" instead of a pronoun if avoidable. Thank you.

Okay, noted. No offense intended, I just didn't know. @Trish

@Trish Interesting though that you are well aware of personal integrity and wellbeing and step up for it (I respect that). I think also new users who feel offended or hurt (up to downright shocked for life) by a VTC deserve that right. That just on a sidenote.
